# XCode 6 / Swift - convert google admob setup instruction to Swift from objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob, ads

just finished my first ios app, and i tried to add ads by google admob and the instructions are in objective-c.
My app is coded in swift and i can't find tutorial for the swift coding.

Does anyone know how to add admob ads in swift?

Thank You !

[Admob instructions based objective c](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I found that github repo but I could not get it to validate when I wanted to submit it to the App Store.

I noticed that Google has released a framework now(GoogleMobileAds.framework) and this seemed to help me get the app validated.

I have made a small github repo with what I done o get it work with the framework. Only a small amount of changes. See [here](https://github.com/Maccle415/SwiftAdmob)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Git-Repository](https://github.com/goldenfiredo/Swift_GoogleAd). I used it and it works like a charm!

Comment: According to StackOverflow policies a link is OK, but it should be surrounded with enough info to let the user know if they want to go there. In this case that would be: The Repository name, how it worked well, maybe a code snippet.